# Decorando um JTextField com um icone

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

A minha dúvida é saber se é possível "decorar" um campo, do tipo JTextField ou JFormattedTextField, com um ícone.

Um exemplo seria algo como isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguindo um exemplo, fiz a seguinte classe.

```
package componentes;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class IconTextField extends JTextField 
{
    private static final int ICON_SPACING = 4;
    private Border mBorder;
    private Icon mIcon;

    @Override
    public void setBorder(Border border)
    {
        mBorder = border;

        if (mIcon == null)
        {
            super.setBorder(border);
        } 

        else 
        {
            Border margin = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, mIcon.getIconWidth() + ICON_SPACING, 0, 0);
            Border compoud = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, margin);
            super.setBorder(compoud);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        if (mIcon != null)
        {
            Insets iconInsets = mBorder.getBorderInsets(this);
            mIcon.paintIcon(this, graphics, iconInsets.left, iconInsets.top);
        }
    }

    public void setIcon(Icon icon) 
    {
        mIcon = icon;
        resetBorder();
    }

    private void resetBorder() 
    {
        setBorder(mBorder);
    }
}
```

o que falta é passar uma variável com caminho da imagem e passar um parametro na instanciação.

Comment: Já tentou isso? [Decorating a JTextField with an image and hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40437661/5524514)

Comment: Ou isso ou botar um jlabel com o icone ao lado.

Comment: Então, eu tentei fazer com o exemplo "Decorating a JTextField with an image and hint", porém não vi parâmetros para passar um caminho ou variável com ícone. Poderia tentar me ajudar ? Vou editar a pergunta e colocar como eu fiz, seguindo o exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando [**esta resposta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437661/5524514) do SOEn como base, basta criar as classes `IconTextComponentHelper` e `IconTextField`, adicionando-as no seu projeto. E para utilizar, basta instanciar um objeto do tipo `IconTextField`, passando o icone do tipo `ImageIcon` através do método `setIcon`:

```
IconTextField field = new IconTextField();
//...
field.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icone));
```

Veja um exemplo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 *
 * @author diego
 */
public class JTextFieldDecoratedIcon {

    public void start() throws IOException {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        IconTextField field = new IconTextField();

        URL path = new URL("https://i.imgur.com/WKfl8uV.png");
        Image icone = ImageIO.read(path);

        field.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icone));

        frame.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new JTextFieldDecoratedIcon().start();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Que resulta em:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso a imagem seja maior que o campo, você pode definir as dimensoes, de forma que caiba corretamente no campo, adicionando a linha abaixo:

```
//adicione esta linha e altere as dimensoes conforme o tamanho do campo
icone = icone.getScaledInstance(25, 25, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
field.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icone));
```

Para ficar legal, prefira imagens de icones cuja altura e largura sejam iguais.

As classes `IconTextComponentHelper` e `IconTextField` podem ser encontradas [**neste link**](https://gist.github.com/diegofelipem/52566bd60542618a10517601960baf3e).

Comment: Muitoo Obrigado !