# Erro ao adicionar placeholder a um componente de texto

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Eu estou implementando o componente [desse tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170767/decorando-um-jtextfield-com-um-icone) juntamente com a seguinte instrução:

```
PromptSupport.setPrompt("Digite..", field);
```

Este comando é da `biblioteca swingx-core-1.6.2` e adiciona uma espécie de `placeholder`. Porém ao utiliza-lo juntamente com o evento `FocusListener` de um `IconTextField` ele me da o seguinte erro:

> ```
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$Handler.propertyChange(DefaultCaret.java:1846)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
>     at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.setBorder(JComponent.java:1796)
>     at geral.IconTextField.setBorder(IconTextField.java:45)
>     at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.BuddyLayoutAndBorder.replaceBorderIfNecessary(BuddyLayoutAndBorder.java:56)
>     at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.BuddyLayoutAndBorder.propertyChange(BuddyLayoutAndBorder.java:245)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:328)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
>     at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.setBorder(JComponent.java:1796)
>     at geral.IconTextField.setBorder(IconTextField.java:45)
>     at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.BuddyLayoutAndBorder.replaceBorderIfNecessary(BuddyLayoutAndBorder.java:56)
>     at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.BuddyLayoutAndBorder.propertyChange(BuddyLayoutAndBorder.java:245)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:328)
>     at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
>     at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.setBorder(JComponent.java:1796)
>     at geral.IconTextField.setBorder(IconTextField.java:45)
> ```

O que eu posso fazer para resolver?

[Link da biblioteca](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingxcore162jar.htm)(role a página quase ao fim, e baixe o 1º link)

Abaixo vou deixar as classes que estou utilizando:

Classe principal:

```
public class JTextFieldDecoratedIcon {

    public void start() throws IOException {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 350));

        JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
        IconTextField field = new IconTextField();

        URL path = new URL("https://i.imgur.com/WKfl8uV.png");
        Image icone = ImageIO.read(path);

        field.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icone));

        frame.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 30));

        //bibilioteca swingx-core-1.6.2 ↓
        PromptSupport.setPrompt("Digite..", field);

        frame.add(field2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        field2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));

        field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                field.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(108, 85, 255)));
                field.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                field.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                field.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            }
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new JTextFieldDecoratedIcon().start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Classe IconTextComponentHelper :

```
class IconTextComponentHelper {
    private static final int ICON_SPACING = 4;

    private Border mBorder;
    private Icon mIcon;
    private Border mOrigBorder;
    private JTextComponent mTextComponent;

    IconTextComponentHelper(JTextComponent component) {
        mTextComponent = component;
        mOrigBorder = component.getBorder();
        mBorder = mOrigBorder;
    }

    Border getBorder() {
        return mBorder;
    }

    void onPaintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (mIcon != null) {
            Insets iconInsets = mOrigBorder.getBorderInsets(mTextComponent);
            mIcon.paintIcon(mTextComponent, g, iconInsets.left, iconInsets.top);
        }
    }

    void onSetBorder(Border border) {
        mOrigBorder = border;

        if (mIcon == null) {
            mBorder = border;
        } else {
            Border margin = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, mIcon.getIconWidth() + ICON_SPACING, 0, 0);
            mBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, margin);
        }
    }

    void onSetIcon(Icon icon) {
        mIcon = icon;
        resetBorder();
    }

    private void resetBorder() {
        mTextComponent.setBorder(mOrigBorder);
    }
}
```

Classe IconTextField:

```
public class IconTextField extends JTextField {

    private IconTextComponentHelper mHelper = new IconTextComponentHelper(this);

    public IconTextField() {

    super();
}

public IconTextField(int cols) {
    super(cols);
}

private IconTextComponentHelper getHelper() {
    if (mHelper == null) {
        mHelper = new IconTextComponentHelper(this);
    }

    return mHelper;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    getHelper().onPaintComponent(graphics);
}

public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
    getHelper().onSetIcon(icon);
}

public void setIconSpacing(int spacing) {
    //getHelper().onSetIconSpacing(spacing);
}

@Override
    public void setBorder(Border border) {
        getHelper().onSetBorder(border);
        super.setBorder(getHelper().getBorder());
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que não tem como saber pois sua versão não possui documentação. Ou você abre mao dessa modificação e deixa somente a da lib ou atualiza a lib para uma versão mais recente e adapta seu código pra ela.

Comment: quando você diz adaptar,  é achar uma instrução ou a maneira de implementar aquele comando ?

Comment: Não, a classe `PromptSupport` manipula eventos de foco para exibir o placeholder, você vai obter o mesmo erro em qualquer versão dessa lib, a não ser que descubra o código fonte dessa classe e modifique. Claro que você corre o risco de "zoar" a classe e ela deixe de funcionar corretamente. Acho que o melhor é você escolher se quer o placeholder ou se quer aplicar ele com foco personalizado por conta propria(o que nem é muito dificil de fazer)

Comment: Então, com setText("") eu consigo fazer, so que tem um porém, em dado momento, eu uso com document Listener esse campo, ai ele zoa as buscas que eu faço.

Comment: Bom, achei uma solução alternativa se utilizar lib nenhuma, porém a pergunta é sobre um erro ao usar a lib, se eu responder, corro o risco de ser negativado por fugir do escopo. Se me permite, posso fazer uma pequena alteração na pergunta de forma que minha resposta alternativa não fique sem sentido pra ela, tudo bem?

Comment: @diegofm pode sim, fique a vontade, e já agradeço a sua ajuda !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de testar várias vezes, percebi que a classe dessa lib se utiliza dos *listeners* de foco para aplicar o *placeholder*, e quando você tenta sobrescrever os métodos de foco, entra em loop infinito, pois seu código altera o campo e notifica o *listener*, que ativa o evento da classe pra aplicar o *placeholder*, e assim fica repetindo infinitamente.

Isso poderia ser resolvido se entendêssemos melhor como funciona a classe `PromptSupport` até exibir o placeholder e alterarmos direto nela, algo que acho mais complicado que criar uma classe própria com essa funcionalidade.

E para implementar um placeholder no `JTextfield`, você precisa monitorar o foco do componente. Baseado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13033751/5524514) e [nesta outra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27740330/5524514) no SOEn, elaborei a classe `PlaceHolderSupport` como alternativa a esta lib:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.FocusManager;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

/**
 * Classe responsável por definir um placeholder a um componente de texto
 * 
 * @author diego
 *
 */
public class PlaceHolderSupport {

    private static JTextComponent textComponent;
    private static String placeHolder = "";

    /**
     * Aplica o texto recebido como placeholder ao componente de texto
     * 
     * @param comp - Componente de texto
     * @param strPlaceHolder - texto do placeholder
     */
    public static void setPlaceHolder(JTextComponent comp, String strPlaceHolder) {

        textComponent = comp;
        placeHolder = strPlaceHolder;
    }

    /**
     * Desenha uma string centralizada no meio do componente representado pelo
     * retangulo
     * 
     * @param g - Instancia de Graphics.
     * @param text - String a ser desenhada.
     * @param rect - Retangulo para centralizar o texto.
     * @param font - Fonte a ser aplicada ao texto
     */
    private static void drawPlaceHolderString(Graphics g, String text, Rectangle rect, Font font) {
        // Obtém as métricas da fonte do texto
        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        // Determina a coordenada X do texto conforme
        // o tamanho da borda interna esquerda
        int x = textComponent.getBorder().getBorderInsets(textComponent).left;
        // Determina a coordenada Y do texto para que
        // fique centralizado verticalmente
        int y = rect.y + ((rect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent();
        // aplica a fonte
        g.setFont(font);
        // desenha a string
        g.drawString(text, x, y);
    }

    /**
     * Desenha o placeholder no componente de texto
     * 
     * @param g - instancia de Graphics
     */
    public static void onPaintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (textComponent != null) {
            //verifica se o campo está vazio e se 
            //o foco atual do teclado pertence a ele
            if (textComponent.getText().isEmpty()
                    && !(FocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner() == textComponent)) {
                Font font = textComponent.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC);
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
                drawPlaceHolderString(g, placeHolder, textComponent.getBounds(), font);
            } else {
                textComponent.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Para utilizar, você precisa passar o texto do *placeHolder* e a instancia do componente de texto no construtor desta classe, através do método `setPlaceHolder`. No seu exemplo da classe `IconTextField`, ficou assim:

```
public IconTextField() {
    super();
    PlaceHolderSupport.setPlaceHolder(this, "Preencha este campo...");
}

public IconTextField(int cols) {
    super(cols);
    PlaceHolderSupport.setPlaceHolder(this, "Preencha este campo...");
}
```

Depois, no método `paintComponent` do seu componente de texto, adicione o seguinte trecho:

```
PlaceHolderSupport.onPaintComponent(graphics);
```

O método `PlaceHolderSupport.onPaintComponent`  verifica se o componente está vazio e fora de foco. Caso a condição seja verdadeira, ele aplica o *placeHolder*, e quando essa condição não for verdadeira, ele força o componente a redesenhar sem o texto.

Sugiro também que faça uma pequena modificação ao adicionar o evento de foco no componente, pois percebi que você tenta recuperar as cores de plano de fundo e bordas padrões ao perder foco e dependendo do [Look And Feel](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_and_Feel) aplicado, pode não ter o resultado esperado. Para sempre obter a cor de fundo padrão, você pode alterar conforme abaixo:

```
field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    Color defaultBg = field.getBackground();

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        field.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(108, 85, 255)));
        field.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        field.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        field.setBackground(defaultBg);
    }
});
```

Com essas alterações, o seu componente já está funcional com o placeholder aplicado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: so uma dúvida, aquele método    public void setIconSpacing(int spacing) 
    {
        getHelper().onSetIconSpacing(spacing);
    }  ele me pede para crirar onSetIconSpacing, faz difereça comentar essa linha ?

Comment: @Java no código original no SOEn, o autor do código não implementou esse método no helper. Acredito que ele tenha desistido, já que está usando uma constante `ICON_SPACING` pra definir esse espaçamento, e tenha esquecido de remover na resposta dele. Pode remover sem problema.

Comment: desculpa a minha ignorância, so pra revisar os passos, acho que eu "comi barriga", dentro do iconText eu passo aqueles dois construtores, e na classe que eu utilizo, so instanciar normal ?

Comment: @Java o importante é adicionar a linha `PlaceHolderSupport.setPlaceHolder(this, "Preencha este campo...");` no construtor(ou nos construtores) do seu componente, e como o seu tem mais de um, apenas copiei os dois pra não correr risco de você adicionar somente em um, usar o outro e não funcionar.  Claro que se quiser, você pode personalizar os construtores, para que recebam o placeHolder como parâmetro ao invés de passar o valor direto como eu fiz, mas ai fica a sua escolha a personalização.

Comment: não sei o que acontece, não aparece o texto

Comment: @Java está funcionando normalmente no seu código, desde que você não tenha alterado nada na classe, claro: https://gist.github.com/diegofelipem/a349619d30b523347e72143feabf49d0

Comment: pra setar o PlaceHolder, ele requer que o componente comece com focu ?

Comment: @Java não, você só tem que seguir o que eu expliquei na resposta. O placeholder vai aparecer quando o componente estiver sem foco. Compila e roda esse codigo do link ai, é o seu código com a classe aplicada.

Comment: sim, já fiz isso, o seu exemplo esta correto. É provavelmente alguma coisa no meu projeto que não esta certo. Só mais uma duvida, pra setar a imagem não pode usar icon em vez de URL ?

Comment: @Java eu sempre utilizo ImageIO: `Image icone = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("path-da-imagem.extensao"));`

Comment: @Java fiz uma pequena alteração no código, pra ele ficar mais independente. Depois dá uma olhada.

Comment: não consegui identificar diferença, o que foi mudado ?

Comment: @Java https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/220707/revisions Antes eu estava pedindo que adicionasse um trecho de if no método `paintComponent` do campo de texto, eu movi ele pra classe `PlaceHolderSupport`, e agora só precisa adicionar uma linha nesse método: `PlaceHolderSupport.onPaintComponent(graphics);`

Comment: vixi, aqui bugo tudo, sera que é o lookFeel ?

Comment: @java, se da forma como estava antes funcionou normal, deixa com estava antes mesmo. É que alterei e testei aqui e como o resultado foi o mesmo, achei que não afetaria nada pra você também.